# Movie with a scene where a robot hunter (I think) tells another person during dinner that you can recognize a cyborg by the creases in their fingers

Tags: story-identification, movie, cyborg

The cop or cyborg hunter tells another person how you can recognize a cyborg/robot. The waitress in the dinner shows her hands and they have deep creases in the area behind the knuckles (I think), proving she's a robot.

I think the movie was made in or around the '80s. The hunter may (I'm not sure) have travelled back in time. Please help, been driving me crazy on and off for a few years now.

Comment: No hurry, but just letting you know that you can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 9):

*[Westworld](https://www.mic.com/articles/161130/westworld-movie-vs-the-hbo-show-what-are-the-big-differences)* (2016), possibly, although I now see it's way later than your timeframe.

> The Hosts in the movies do have one thing that clearly separates them from the humans. The people who created them had trouble with the hands, which is why every robot has distinctive creases where their fingers bend.

Found with a search for `film robots "creases * fingers"`

The series is based off of a 1973 film, of course, which had a similar check for hands, but it was about the palms, [which were too smooth](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0070909/characters/nm0291266).

> **Peter Martin**: What's the matter with you?
> **Technician**: Hold out your hands. Lemme see your hands!... You're a guest! You really gave me a scare. Look, ah, everything's broken down! The machines have gone crazy!

Comment: Thanks FuzzyBoots, but id need to watch the film again to confirm. I watched the original westworld, once relased on uk tv, about 1977. It may be it. Ill try and find it to check, regards Sean.

Comment: :) If you've also seen that scene from the TV show, it could be the two got mixed in your head. I've had that happen before.

Comment: I'm fairly confident that it's the film version of Westworld. I remember the scene, and definitely haven't seen the TV variant.

Comment: Not watched the series and only seen the original film once, with yul brinner as the gunslinger. Ill find it and watch. Hopefully thats the answer. Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: I haven't watched the 1973 movie, but the robots in the TV show are almost perfectly indistinguishable from human beings. So it must be the film version